# cURL script - visiting subdomains of a page

Tags: curl

I would like to know what should I write if I want to visit and load all subdomains of a certain page.

Example: I want cUrl to visit 1000 subdomains, starting from www.example.com/page1 to www.example.com/page1000

I already figured out some stuff however I don't know how to finish it. This is what I worked-out so far:

(curl -X POST -d "$post_data"  "www.example.com/page$x")

I don't know how to write exactly that $x is 1 to 1000
I also don't know how to write the start and finish of it...

Thankx for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not. You can do by placing the number inside the `[]`. For doing curl on all pages from `1-1000` here is the example:

```
curl -X POST -d "$post_data" "http://www.example.com/page[1-1000]"
                                          Notice here    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank You! And that is all what I have to write into script? I'm writing it into notepad.

Comment: @JohnnyRei Yes, Just make sure your `-d` gets some values like `x=y&b=123`

Comment: Dear Sabuj - I got it now. You've helped me a great deal - thank YOu so much and I hope Your day is totally awesome! Cheers! JOhn